# Const arguments binding to non-const references in C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates, reference, constants

Consider something like:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T& x) 
{
    ....       
}
```

Why does something like **`const`** `int` binds to `f(T&)`?

This seems to me kind of a violation of *const-correctness*. In fact, if `f()` takes a *non*-const `T&` reference, then it's very likely that `f()` will *modify* its argument (else, `f()` would have been defined as `void f(const T&)`).

In code like this:

```
template <typename T>
inline void f(T& x) 
{
    x = 0;
}

int main() 
{
    int n = 2;
    f(n);

    const int cn = 10;
    f(cn);
}
```

the compiler tries to call `f()` with `T = const int`, then of course there is an error message because of the `x = 0;` assignment inside `f()`'s body.
This is the error message from GCC:

> ```
> test.cpp: In instantiation of 'void f(T&) [with T = const int]':
> test.cpp:13:9:   required from here
> test.cpp:4:7: error: assignment of read-only reference 'x'
>      x = 0;
>        ^
> ```

But why does the compiler try to bind a **const** argument with a function template which takes a  *non*-const parameter?

What's the *rationale* behind this C++ template rule?

Comment: Because.. you asked it to try? Or did I miss something? Look at the *type* in the error message, `T = const int`. The `T` is `const`, the reference is not involved until after that's been settled.

Comment: My expectation was that the error were at a "higher level", e.g. _can't bind `const int` to `f(T&)`. Instead the error is caused by the assignment inside `f()`.

Comment: It wouldn't be an error if you weren't doing the assignment, so again, I'm not following. `T` isn't `int`; its `const int`.  I think that is the hurdle you're struggling to get over.

Comment: I think he wants the compiler to not take the template into consideration because the function can't work with a const argument, and then tell you so directly via a new error message.  But this is another step to take for compiler writers, with only little benefit.

Comment: @CarlColijn: You got my point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::enable_if` plus e.g. `std::is_const` to avoid that `T` binds to a `const` type.

---

Re …

> “What's the rationale behind this C++ template rule?”

it can possibly be found in Bjarne's design-and-evolution book, but about the most common rationale is that the rules have been chosen for simplicity and uniformity, and so it appears to be also here: treating some types in special ways would introduce needless complexity.

Comment: +1. totally how I would do it, or i'd provide an overload for `T const&`. [See it live](http://ideone.com/tE1gs3)

Comment: My expectation was that the C++ compiler would do that (without requiring me to use `std::enable_if`, etc.), since I did _not_ write `const T&`, but just `T&`. Instead, the burden is on the programmer who must use `std::enable_if`, etc. This doesn't seem to me "treating some types in special ways". And it seems that this current behavior introduces "needless complexity", since to exclude `const` (which I didn't write in the function template parameter), `std::enable_if`+other must be used.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Thanks for the code sample. You may want to write an answer with that, and I'd vote it up. Anyway, it seems to me that I'm doing more work to exclude `T&` binding with `const int`, instead I would have expected the compiler to do that for me (without requiring me to use `std::enable_if`+etc.), since I wrote `T&` and not `const T&` as `f()` parameter.

Comment: @Mr.C64: it's in the nature of special case rules that the special case such a rule is about, is (usually) simplified. at the cost of complexity elsewhere. for example, consider writing a single function template that handles any type, `const` or not.

Comment: @Mr.C64 No worries. Alf answered it, I just implemented a sample. The real noodle-baker is providing an overload: `template<typename T> void f(T const&)` in which case the sample I linked would work in *both* cases and not introduce ambiguity, while `T& const` would break the first-call on an ambiguous resolution. It isn't any wonder committees were needed to settle the behavior in this.

Comment: In addition, as others suggested to me, it's possible to use also `static_assert` (with the addition of a custom error message), e.g. `static_assert(!std::is_const<T>::value, "T shouldn't be const.");`.

Answer (score 8):

`T` binds to `const int`.

To avoid that, you may use SFINAE:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_const<T>::value, void>::type
f(T& arg) {}
```

or **deleted** function:

```
template <typename T> void f(T& arg) {}
template <typename T> void f(const T&) = delete;
```

Comment: +1 for the deleted function. I keep forgetting that is supported even outside member-fns in C++11. nice alternative and gives the OP more of what he's looking for (direct, look-here, you-can't-do-that) messaging.

Answer (score 0):

```
const int cn = 10;
```

That means 'cn' is const, you can't change it in anyway, anywhere and anytime.

More:

```
const int cia = 10;
int ia = 10;
```

The type of cia is different with ia. So T will be const int, not int.

```
typedef const int      cint;
cint cia = 10;
int ia = 10;
```

T will be used as cint, not int.

Comment: Pretty sure he has a handle on this.