# How to force, value to be lvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lvalue, function-templates

I want my function to take a *lvalue* reference and absolutely not a *rvalue* or *temporary* or whatever.

This is my function:

```cpp
template<class T>
void foo(T& value) {}

// Imagine I have a class Foo
struct Foo
{ 
   int a;
   int b;
};
```

When I call `foo(Foo{1, 2})`, first, it compiles even if I asked for a *lvalue* reference, and second, it doesn't work because `foo` stores the address of the passed value, so I get garbage when I read it later.

How to force `foo` to take a *lvalue* reference?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50852470/how-to-force-a-function-to-only-accept-an-lvalue-reference-parameter

Comment: With your given code snippets `foo(Foo(1, 2))` does not compile.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-referencebinding-enforce-reference-binding-rules?view=vs-2019

Comment: What compiler are you using? VS2019 emits a `warning C4239: nonstandard extension used: 'argument': conversion from 'Foo' to 'T &'` or an `error C2664: 'void foo<Foo>(T &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Foo' to 'T &'`, depending on if languages extensions are enabled or disabled.

Comment: That doesn't work at all: See [on coliru](//coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65fa816c3f20d1cf)

Comment: I fixed the compile error

Comment: @Kiosto Still it can't be: https://godbolt.org/z/oyhayR, unless you have MSVS: https://godbolt.org/z/PAML25, with non-standard extensions on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, the given code will not compile by default in [GCC and Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/RfjVi-), only in [MSVC with non-standard extensions](https://godbolt.org/z/PPTyvo).

If you want to make sure that `foo()` does not accept an rvalue, just [`delete` that overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions):

```
template<class T>
void foo(T&& value) = delete;
```

Comment: That’s a universal reference, so it triggers regardless of value category.  You’re relying on partial ordering to prefer the lvalue-reference choice; better would be to constrain the deleted function template so that it doesn’t outcompete normal functions that require conversions.